# Php search mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

Sorry if I'm asking an already answered question, but I was not able to find my specific set-up.

I have a php file called functions.php, where I store all my functions and where I prepare my database.
A small example would be as follows:

```
function getUsers()
{
        global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
                id,
                user_name,
                FROM db_users");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $user);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){
                $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'user_name' => $user);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return ($row);
}
```

I want to make a search function, with a form where I can search with OPTION VALUES, i.e values as: `id`, `user_name`.

By having functions.php I am already establishing the connection to the mysql database, 
How can I search the database with my `'%searchrequest%'` with a search.php?

Or do you suggest another solution?

Comment: You concatenate id & usename and set as value of the option.post the form nd build the query as need.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass these search values into your current function. If nothing is passed,it will fetch all the data. If there is any value passed it will filter based on it.

```
function getUsers($id="",$user_name="")
{
        global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

        $query = "SELECT
                id,
                user_name,
                FROM db_users WHERE 1 = 1 ";
        if(trim($id)) 
           $query .= " AND id = '".$id."'"; 

        if(trim($user_name)) 
           $query .= " AND user_name = '".$user_name."'"; 


        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);


        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $user);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){
                $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'user_name' => $user);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return ($row);
}
```

Comment: Are you not just replacing query with a different ones instead of concatinating them ?

Comment: @MikeWu - well pointed out! I hate when I mistype such places!

Comment: Thanks, going to try this soon!